# Why don't two air masses just mix in the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science, weather

In weather fronts, two air masses of different temperature, density etc. meet and one just moves over or under the other. Why do these two just mix together? What is the physical mechanism that prevents it?

Comment: Because they can't go to equilibrium at an instant.  For instance they can equalize their T just thought the front. The masses far from the front will still be moving according to their parameters. It is just relative to the size and the time scale.  Similar things will happen in a very small container but to see that you should specifically design an experiment.